# Find max in-order difference in array

Tags: python, algorithm, programming-challenge, array, time-limit-exceeded

Given an array A of integers, find the maximum of j - i subjected to the constraint of A[i] <= A[j].

If there is no solution possible, return 0.

**Example :**

A : [3 5 4 2]

Output : 2 
for the pair (3, 4)

***My Code*** :

```
def maximumGap(self, A):
    if len(A)==1: return  0
    a_list = sorted(([Val,indeX] for indeX,Val in enumerate(A)), reverse=True)

    rest = [indeX for val,indeX in a_list] # rest stores all the index from a_list which is sorted in decreasing order
    len_rest = len(rest)
    del a_list[:]
    results = []

    for i in range(len_rest):
        if i != len_rest-1:
            results.append(rest[i] - min(rest[i+1:]))
        else: continue

    ans = max(results)
    if ans < 0: return 0
    else: return ans
```

***Sample input*** taken for explanation:

```
A = [34, 8, 10, 3, 2, 80, 30, 33, 1]
```

Brief summary of my algorithm:

**1.** a_list is a list of lists which will store all the numbers from the orginal list (list A) in sorted order along with their indexes.

```
`a_list = [[80, 5], [34, 0], [33, 7], [30, 6], [10, 2], [8, 1], [3, 3], [2, 4], [1, 8]]`
```

**2.** rest is a list which will store all the indexes from a_list.

```
`rest = [5, 0, 7, 6, 2, 1, 3, 4, 8]`
```

(After this, a_list is deleted to empty the space)

**3.** Now, the crux of the logic is:
Since list is sorted in descending order, I need not take care of the **constraint: A[i] <= A[j]**

I will just iterate the *list: rest* and in each iteration, say 0th iteration, rest[0] = 5 is subtracted from the smallest remaining elements in *list: rest*

Each result of the iteration is stored in *list: results*

**4.** `results = [5, -1, 6, 5, 1, -2, -1, -4]`

**5.** Max of *list results* will give me the answer.

(It is important to note that while sorting the list we must also store the original index of the values instead of blindly sorting it.)

***Now, coming to the actual problem:***

On submitting my solution at *interviewbit* website, my code is giving correct answers to all test cases but **time limit is exceeded**

I am not able to figure out what how to optimise this further.

Time complexity of my code,correct me if i am wrong, is **O(N log N)**

Sorting takes O(N log N) time in the worst case when using sort function in python.

**My main question** is how to optimise this code further?

Found on www.interviewbit.com

Comment: Your indentation seems to be off. The method inside the class should not be on the same level as the class

Comment: there is a solution in a o(N) complexity: [see](http://www.hackinghat.com/index.php/python/calculating-peak-to-trough-drawdown), you only have to keep track of the lowest value seen yet and compute the difference between the current point and the lowest value seen yet

Answer (score -1):

Actually in the last part, during the iteration over list named rest, its O(N^2), so, its not working.
Refer to [Geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-an-array-arr-find-the-maximum-j-i-such-that-arrj-arri/) for O(n).

Comment: Links can rot. Please include the main content in the body of your answer and provide the link for reference.